# Sizing of HTML Elements Relative to Screen Instead of Parent

Tags: html, css

Currently I am trying to figure out if there is a way to set the size of an html element relative to the size of the screen instead of the size of its parent element using percentages. I would like to do this to create uniformity in the size of images across my site.

I'd like to use percentages to ensure that my images resize appropriately in response to a change in browser resizing.

For example, if I set the width of an image to "width: 60%;" I would like my image to take up 60% of the screen space, instead of 60% of the div that it is nested in.

Is there a method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

yes: you can use the `vw` and `vh` units. These represent percentages of the viewport (= browser window, but in full screen mode and on mobile devices this equals the screen size) width and height.